# How do I remove test code that sticks to the Info Panel?

Tags: scripting, text-editor

I recently done some work on an app, "Goodies Menu" as you'll see. Every one of those items (add-ons) have some veryatation with their, which is why I suspect their is no where that I can find to remove them. I've be doing some searching for the following woods, (which left me know where). Goodies menu.py, pie_views_numpad_menu.py

!Blender\2.80[RC2]\blender-2.80.0-git.ac8c795429f9-windows64\2.80\scripts\addons\space_view3d_pie_menus\pie_views_numpad_menu.py

[image: Info Panel - text editor will not remove these text codes. They all have a variation in the code somewhere.]

Answer (score 3):

**Reload Scripts.**

Go to the python console and type in:

```
bpy.ops.script.reload()
```

Or press <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the *Search Menu* and type `Reload Scripts`:

[image]

You will have to run any non registered script again to have a single menu.  I have this operator prepended to my py console and text editor areas.

Or temporarily tack it to top of script while developing.

It had the default keymap  <kbd>F8</kbd> in 2.7x and prior.